# Ruta abrir archivos python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, pillow

Tengo un código `python 3.7` en `tkinter` y la aplicación abre un archivo *jpg* y *pdf* mediante la llamada desde un botón creado. Al momento de crear el ejecutable abre normalmente en mi PC, pero en PC ajenas a la mía no funciona.

El código que he creado para esta aplicación es la siguiente:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
import os

class sismicidad():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vent_sismi = tk.Tk()
        self.vent_sismi.iconbitmap("sismo_ico_1.ico")
        self.vent_sismi.title("SISMICIDAD")
        self.pest_sismor = ttk.Notebook(self.vent_sismi)
        self.pest_sismor.grid(row=0, column = 0)
        self.sismorresistente_1()
        self.perf_suelos()
        self.zona_sismi()
        self.sismor_funcion()
        self.z_sismi_funcion()
        self.vent_sismi.mainloop()

#Funciones para la estructura de la pestaña SONAS SISMORRESISTENTE:
    def sismorresistente_1(self):
        ...
#Funcion de CERRAR:
    def cerrar_sismicidad(self):
       ...

#Funciones para la estructura de la pestaña de PERFILES DE SUELOS:
    def perf_suelos(self):
        ...
    #Mostrar Tabla de Vs:
    def abrir_vs(self):
        self.im = Image.open("C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/sismicidad/tabla_perf.jpg")
        self.im.show()

    #Funciones para PERFILES DE SUELOS:
    def sismor_funcion(self,event=None):

        self.x1=self.entry_1.get()

        while True:
            if self.x1 > 1500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S0: Roca Dura.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 500 and self.x1 <= 1500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S1: Roca y Suelos muy rigidos.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 180 and self.x1 <= 500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S2: Suelos Intermedios.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 0 and self.x1 <= 180:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S3: Suelos Blandos.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 == 0:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            break

#Funciones para la estrutura de la pestaña ZONAS SISMICAS:
    def zona_sismi(self, event=None):
        ...
    def abrir_norma(self):
        os.popen("C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/sismicidad/norma_tecnica_e_030.pdf")

    def z_sismi_funcion(self, event=None):

        self.datos = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/sismicidad/distri_sism_1.csv", encoding="latin9", sep=";")
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.datos)

        self.x2 = self.entry_2.get()

        self.x2 = str.upper(self.x2)

        for self.idx in self.df.index:

            if self.df.DISTRITO[self.idx] == self.x2:
                ...
                break
        else:
            ...

aplicacion = sismicidad()
```

Como se muestra en el código, se llama al archivo *jpg* y *pdf* pero con la ruta que está en mi PC, pero quiero una ruta o algún consejo para que se pueda abrir en otra PC.

Muestro el error que arroja cuando abro la aplicación en otra PC.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como ruteo para que abra en otra pc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno para que te funcione en cualquier maquina utiliza path's que no sean fijos, yo recomendaría usar `os.getcwd()` para poder obtener la ruta y luego concatenar con la carpeta donde guardas tu imagen y pdf ([Ésta es la documentación de ese método](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)).

Primeramente debes mover los recursos dentro de tu proyecto, algo así:

> -- mi_proyecto
> ------ imagenPdfFiles
> ---------- tabla_perf.jpg
> ---------- archivo_pdf.pdf
> ------ sismicidad.py

**Ahora veamos un ejemplo:**

Tu tienes lo siguiente:

```
self.im = Image.open("C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/sismicidad/tabla_perf.jpg")
```

En lugar de esto puedes hacer:

```
self.im = Image.open(os.getcwd() + "/imagenPdfFiles/tabla_perf.jpg")
```

Obviamente una vez que hayas movido tus recursos (imagen y pdf) dentro de tu proyecto.

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: Ok... voy a intentarlo....