# Imagen en otra carpeta tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Como estan estimados?, Estoy desarrollando una app en python utilizando tkinter y bueno tiene muchos archivos y asi que decidi por hacer carpetas, en una de esas carpeta hay una imagen que nesesito abrir, el problema no es el codigo porque funciona, es como le digo a tkinter que la imagen esta en esa carpeta

```
imagen = tk.PhotoImage(file="boto_prueba.png")
```

ese seria la imagen que nesesito el problema es que esta en la carpeta **Imagenes** dentro del proyecto como podria llamarla?

```
Proyecto
    main.py
    Imagenes
        boton_prueba.png(esta imagen nesesito en main.py)
```

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336581/ruta-abrir-archivos-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependiendo del sistema operativo que estés utilizando, tendrás menos problemas si usas rutas absolutas

- abspath() calculas la ruta absoluta del archivo main
- dirname() obtienes la ruta del directorio padre
- join() une los parámetros como una ruta

```py
import os

file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
imagen_path = os.path.join(file_path, 'Imagenes', 'boto_prueba.png')

# ...

imagen = tk.PhotoImage(file=imagen_path)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes solucionar sencillamente colocando la ruta

```
imagen = tk.PhotoImage(file="imagenes/boto_prueba.png")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hno!