# mostrar imagen en barra de titulo de ventana tkinter ubicada en carpeta distinta de la app

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda, estoy aprendiendo.
Tengo escrito este código y funciona perfecto cuando la imagen `exit.png` se encuentra en la misma carpeta que la app.

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter.ttk import *

raiz = Tk()

raiz.geometry('400x300')

ruta_foto = os.getcwd()

print(ruta_foto)

foto = PhotoImage(file='exit.png')

raiz.iconphoto (False, foto)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Para ordenar, cambio la ubicación de la imagen `exit.png` poniéndola dentro de una carpeta llamada `imagenes` que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta de la app, sale el siguiente error:

```
/home/carlos/A_programacion/A_tkinter-python3/Ejercicios-tkinter

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "uso_de_iconphoto.py", line 77, in <module>
    foto = PhotoImage(file='exit.png')

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3545, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3501, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "exit.png": no such file or directory
```

Intente modificar la ubicación de `exit.png` agregándole una ruta relativa a imágenes modificando el código de esta forma:

```
foto = PhotoImage(file='imagenes/exit.png')
```

Y aparece el siguiente error:

```
/home/carlos/A_programacion/A_tkinter-python3/Ejercicios-tkinter

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "uso_de_iconphoto.py", line 77, in <module>
    foto = PhotoImage(file='imagenes/exit.png')

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3545, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3501, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "imagenes/exit.png": no such file or directory
```

Intente modificando de esta otra forma :

```
foto = PhotoImage(file='/imagenes/exit.png')
```

Y da este error:

```
/home/carlos/A_programacion/A_tkinter-python3/Ejercicios-tkinter

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "uso_de_iconphoto.py", line 78, in <module>
    foto = PhotoImage(file='/imagenes/exit.png')

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3545, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3501, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "/imagenes/exit.png": no such file or directory
```

Busque en la clase `PhotoImage` y no encuentro que puede estar mal.
No me doy cuenta porque tengo este error.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas obtener la ruta absoluta al directorio donde se encuentra tu archivo, esto lo haces por medio del modulo `os` tal como lo indica está respuesta [Imagen en otra carpeta tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344874/imagen-en-otra-carpeta-tkinter/344878#344878)

Yo particularmente utilizo `os.path.abspath` por ejemplo, para obtener una imagen que se encuentra en la carpeta imágenes pongo:

```
import os

path_imagen = os.path.abspath("imagenes\\logo.jpg")
```

Esto me arroja *'C:\Users\Colo\Downloads\notas 1.8\imagenes\logo.jpg'*

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme.!